# Have a ActionFilter look to a hypothetical ActionArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am building a .net core mvc application that needs to be multi-language. I have set up my route so that a language is part of the request.

```
"{language=nl}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

On my controller I have Actions they all have a language parameter

```
 public IActionResult Hello(int id, string language){
     _bussinslayer.SetLanguage(language);
     //do actual work
 }
```

This is working as expected. However, I will have a lot of actions, they will all have it, and they will all do the same with it. Setting the language on the underlying system.

So I created a ActionFilterAttribute basically doing

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
     //input validation
     var language = filterContext.ActionArguments["language"] as string;
     _bussinslayer.SetLanguage(language);
 }
```

Which is also still working, **until I remove the language parameter from the action**. At that point the language argument is no longer in the ActionArguments collection.

```
 //This work, but the language parameter is unused
 public IActionResult Hello(int id, string language){         
     //do actual work
 }

 //This no longer works
 public IActionResult Hello(int id){         
     //do actual work
 }
```

In retrospective, it does make some sense that the argument is not in the collection if there is no parameter. But I would like access to the value as if the argument was there. how can this be obtained?

Answer (score 0):

It is still in the RouteData.

```
var language = filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"]
```